# Laravel связь моделей

Tags: php, laravel, model

Имеется проблема.

Описание: 
 - Имеется две модели (Join и Object) 
В моделе Join объявлена связь :

```
 public function objects(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Object');
 }
```

В Моделе Object так же объявлена связь:

```
    public function joins(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Join');
    }
```

Собственно в тинкере пытаюсь выполнить команду:

```
Join::find(23)->object->name;
```

Ошибка появляется:

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in Psy Shell code on
>   line 1

Сомнения вызывает то что имеется модель TicketStatus связи идентичны, при выполнении команды

```
Join::find(23)->ticketstatus->name;
```

Ответ верный... 
В чем может быть "Затык" подскажите...

Answer (score 1):

У вас метод object**S**

```
public function objects(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Object');
 }
```

А в тинкере вызываете object

```
Join::find(23)->object->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что человек изменил настройки в БД... 
Удалил миграции и запустил по новой

> php artisan migrate:reset
>
> php artisan migrate

Все заработало. 
Ответ Выше можно считать верным, только я тут в тексте опечатку допустил

Comment: Вопрос ничем не полезен для общества, удалите его. Вместо `migrate:reset` и `migrate` можно использовать `migrate:fresh` - то же самое

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько "Тревога" на вопросе -> "Закрытие" -> "Не по теме" -> "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой." Но вы, возможно, и без меня это знаете.